# WAX config - connection failed - connection refused

Tags: nodeos, mainnet

i'am using wax blockchain with the following config.ini

```
blocks-dir = "blocks"
chain-state-db-size-mb = 181072
contracts-console = false
http-server-address = 0.0.0.0:8888
https-server-address =
http-alias = localhost:8888
http-alias = 127.0.0.1:8888
access-control-allow-credentials = false
p2p-listen-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:9876
p2p-peer-address = peer.wax.alohaeos.com:9876
p2p-peer-address = wax.eu.eosamsterdam.net:9101
p2p-peer-address = wax.blockmatrix.network:13546
p2p-peer-address = peer.wax-mainnet.eosblocksmith.io:5080
p2p-peer-address = seed.blokcrafters.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = p2p.wax.bountyblok.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = wax.cryptolions.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = wax.csx.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = wax.dapplica.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = p2p.eos42.io:9884
p2p-peer-address = p2p-wax.eosarabia.net:9876
p2p-peer-address = wax-p2p.eos.barcelona:9876
p2p-peer-address = wax.eosdac.io:29876
p2p-peer-address = wax.eosdublin.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = p2p.wax.eosdetroit.io:1337
p2p-peer-address = peer1-wax.eosphere.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = br.eosrio.io:35668
p2p-peer-address = p2p2.wax.greeneosio.com:9878
p2p-peer-address = wax-p2p.hkeos.com:19876
p2p-peer-address = wax.eosusa.news:9879
p2p-peer-address = p2p-wax.maltablock.org:9876
p2p-peer-address = wax.eosn.io:9876
p2p-peer-address = seed.wax.gg:9876
p2p-peer-address = wax-peer.eosasia.one:9876
p2p-peer-address = wax.sheos.org:9876
p2p-peer-address = wax.eossweden.eu:9052
p2p-peer-address = waxp2p.eoscafeblock.com:9090
p2p-peer-address = p2p.waxsweden.org:35777
p2p-peer-address = wax.zenblocks.io:13975
p2p-max-nodes-per-host = 1
agent-name = "WAX Agent"
allowed-connection = any
max-clients = 50
sync-fetch-span = 500
pause-on-startup = false
max-transaction-time = 1000
plugin = eosio::chain_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::http_plugin
plugin = eosio::net_api_plugin
```

also i'am using snapshot which was 23000 blocks ahead at the start, and for several hours my node catchup only ~1000 blocks. Typical log output is

```
-----LOT OF misaligned reference---------
    warn  2021-05-09T12:30:22.113 nodeos    wabt.hpp:632                  translate_one        ] misaligned reference
    error 2021-05-09T12:30:22.127 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:2185           operator()           ] connection failed to p2p.eos42.io:9884: Connection refused
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.127 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'p2p.eos42.io:9884', p2p.eos42.io:9884
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.166 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:1070           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to p2p2.wax.greeneosio.com:9878, lib 118221572, head 118221907, id 66dacd8c3152c136
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.209 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
    error 2021-05-09T12:30:22.209 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: p2p2.wax.greeneosio.com:9878
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.210 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'p2p2.wax.greeneosio.com:9878', p2p2.wax.greeneosio.com:9878
    error 2021-05-09T12:30:22.223 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:2185           operator()           ] connection failed to wax.eossweden.eu:9052: Connection refused
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.224 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'wax.eossweden.eu:9052', wax.eossweden.eu:9052
    error 2021-05-09T12:30:22.244 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:2185           operator()           ] connection failed to peer.wax-mainnet.eosblocksmith.io:5080: Connection refused
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.244 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'peer.wax-mainnet.eosblocksmith.io:5080', peer.wax-mainnet.eosblocksmith.io:5080
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.310 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:3090           connection_monitor   ] p2p client connections: 0/50, peer connections: 28/29
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.316 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:1070           operator()           ] Sending handshake generation 1 to wax.eosusa.news:9879, lib 118221572, head 118221908, id 08506e32c6aab919
    error 2021-05-09T12:30:22.342 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:2185           operator()           ] connection failed to waxp2p.eoscafeblock.com:9090: Connection refused
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.343 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'waxp2p.eoscafeblock.com:9090', waxp2p.eoscafeblock.com:9090
    error 2021-05-09T12:30:22.349 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:2185           operator()           ] connection failed to wax.zenblocks.io:13975: Connection refused
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.350 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'wax.zenblocks.io:13975', wax.zenblocks.io:13975
    error 2021-05-09T12:30:22.360 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:2185           operator()           ] connection failed to br.eosrio.io:35668: Connection refused
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.361 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'br.eosrio.io:35668', br.eosrio.io:35668
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.468 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:2350           operator()           ] Peer closed connection
    error 2021-05-09T12:30:22.469 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:2369           operator()           ] Closing connection to: wax.eosusa.news:9879
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.470 net-1     net_plugin.cpp:943            _close               ] closing 'wax.eosusa.news:9879', wax.eosusa.news:9879
    info  2021-05-09T12:30:22.571 net-0     net_plugin.cpp:3090           connection_monitor   ] p2p client connections: 0/50, peer connections: 28/29
    warn  2021-05-09T12:30:23.421 nodeos    wabt.hpp:632                  translate_one        ] misaligned reference
-----LOT OF misaligned reference---------
```

Am i doing something wrong?

server spec:
2 core 3.2 Ghz
24 Gb ram
60 Gb ssd

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to use `database-map-mode = heap` to keep the state in RAM instead of updating it on disk.

After doing that, check your disk i/o.

Also if you don't need history, start from a snapshot instead: https://snapshots.eosnation.io/

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what @Matthew said,
I'd change the wasm-runtime and enable oc-mode for faster transactions-processing:

```
#Override default WASM runtime (wabt)
wasm-runtime = eos-vm-jit

#Enable optimized compilation in WASM 
eos-vm-oc-enable = true
```

Peer-list also looks outdated, use the ones provided [here](https://validate.eosnation.io/wax/reports/config.html)